# environment() bicep function should be used to generate url's instead of hardcoding them

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have a application firewall rule where i need to rewrite some of the targetFqdns which are hardcoded urls, so i instead use the enviroment bicep function.

the urls are:

```html
 targetFqdns: [
     '*.blob.core.windows.net'
     'login.microsoftonline.com'
     'management.core.windows.net'
     'management.azure.com'
     'graph.windows.net'
 ]
```

but when I try to use enviroment() and then deploy the request is invalid

```html
targetFqdns: [ 
    '*.blob.${environment().suffixes.storage}' // '*.blob.core.windows.net'
    '${environment().authentication.loginEndpoint}' // 'login.microsoftonline.com'
    '${environment().authentication.audiences}' // 'management.core.windows.net'
    '${environment().resourceManager}' // 'management.azure.com'
    '${environment().graphAudience}' // 'graph.windows.net'
]
```

enviroment() bicep function docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-deployment#environment

error message from deployment:

```html
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "DeploymentFailed",
        "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
        "details": [
            {
                "code": "BadRequest",
                "message": "{\r\n  \"Message\": \"The request is invalid.\",\r\n  \"ModelState\": {\r\n    \"resource\": [\r\n      \"{\\\"Status\\\":\\\"Failed\\\",\\\"Error\\\":{\\\"Code\\\":\\\"FirewallPolicyApplicationRuleInvalidTargetFqdn\\\",\\\"Message\\\":\\\"Firewall Policy Application Rule dev-firewall-rule has invalid target fqdn https://login.microsoftonline.com/\\\",\\\"Target\\\":null}}\"\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please paste the full error message  ?

Comment: error message added @Thomas

Comment: They are missing this suffix: .servicebus.windows.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation you are referencing, some of the environment() properties are URI not just domain:

```json
{
  "graphAudience": "https://graph.windows.net/",
  "resourceManager": "https://management.azure.com/",
  "authentication": {
    "loginEndpoint": "https://login.windows.net/",
    "audiences": [
      "https://management.core.windows.net/",
      "https://management.azure.com/"
    ]
  }
}
```

you would need to remove `scheme` and `//` from the URI.
Also, the `audiences` property is an array of string:

```bicep
// Extract domains from audience
var authAudienceDomains = [for aud in environment().authentication.audiences: replace(replace(aud, 'https://', ''), '/', '')]

// Concactenate fqdns
output targetFqdns array = concat(
  [
    // *.blob.core.windows.net
    '*.blob.${environment().suffixes.storage}'
    // login.windows.net
    replace(replace(environment().authentication.loginEndpoint, 'https://', ''), '/', '')
    // graph.windows.net
    replace(replace(environment().graphAudience, 'https://', ''), '/', '')
  ],
  // management.core.windows.net and management.azure.com
  authAudienceDomains
)
```